# Android developer training sample code "Retrieving the Current Location"

Tags: java, android, api, location

I am following the training tutorial on this link: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. It gives some exceptions at run time, following is the few initial lines of log trace:

04-04 13:58:41.798: E/AndroidRuntime(16206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.location.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.location-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.location-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]].

Furthermore, I use the lint tool on this sample code. It gives this error: Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.android.location.ReceiveUpdatesIntentService, was not found in the project or the libraries.

Please suggest.